# Fill sequence conditional on other variables in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is my data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Group, ~Year, ~given, ~required,
     "A", 2017L,     3L,        1L,
     "A", 2017L,     4L,        2L,
     "A", 2017L,     8L,        6L,
     "A", 2018L,     1L,        7L,
     "A", 2018L,     4L,       10L,
     "B", 2018L,     8L,        1L,
     "B", 2019L,     3L,        4L,
     "B", 2019L,     4L,        5L)
```

I want to calculate "required" such that, for any "Group":

1. The first entry of the 'required' gets the value of 1.
2. The delta between the 'required' and 'given' variables has to be the same.
3. For any Year, the minimum values for "given" variable could be 1 and the maximum is 8.

How should I calculate 'required' variable using the 'Group', 'Year', and 'given' variables?

Comment: how do you get `required = 7` in 4th row?

Comment: Because it's still for Group A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(required = c(1, diff(given)),
         required = ifelse(required < 0, max(given) - abs(required), required),
         required = cumsum(required)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   Group  Year given required
#   <chr> <int> <int>    <dbl>
# 1 A      2017     3        1
# 2 A      2017     4        2
# 3 A      2017     8        6
# 4 A      2018     1        7
# 5 A      2018     4       10
# 6 B      2018     8        1
# 7 B      2019     3        4
# 8 B      2019     4        5
```

Comment: Try `floor(13/2)`.

Comment: I disagree. It should be `4` because `13` and `4` is 4 number away. Otherwise, you cannot explain in your original exmaple why row 4 is `7`.

Comment: So are you saying as the numbers keep increasing, we only find the smallest difference if the later one is smaller than the previous one?

Comment: Why in your new example the 4th row is 7?

Comment: You are not clear about your rule. I have updated my answer based on the best information I have. It generates the same output for your original example. But for your new example, I think the 4th row should be `12`.

Comment: Small fix df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Group, ~Year, ~given, ~required,
     "A", 2017L,     3L,        1L,
     "A", 2017L,     4L,        2L,
     "A", 2017L,     13L,       11L,
     "A", 2018L,     1L,        12L,
     "A", 2018L,     4L,        15L,
     "B", 2018L,     13L,        1L,
     "B", 2019L,     3L,         4L,
     "B", 2019L,     4L,         5L)

Comment: My code can generate the desired output for both your orignal and updated examples.

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry for the confusion and dragging the comments! Really appreciate it!